# How to scale Azure Application Gateway beyond the 125 instances limit?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, scaling, azure-application-gateway

I want to know if there's a way commonly used for prod environments where if I reach the 125 instances limit for SKU v2, I can keep scaling, or at least I can keep the performance. I tried looking at Azure docs but they don't seem to address this problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup **multiple App Gateways** to expand your number of instances and load balance them using Azure Traffic Manger.  A [reference architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/high-availability/reference-architecture-traffic-manager-application-gateway) shows multiple regions but Traffic Manager can be used for [resources in the same region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/high-availability/reference-architecture-traffic-manager-application-gateway).  I don't know your backend architecture so this may or may not work.

[image]